# How to receive information from View Controller which is embed in Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have two View Controllers "ViewController" and "ChildViewController". connection between them happens with segue if HomeButton is clicked. segue identifier is "parentToChild". if ChildButton is clicked information goes to "ViewController" using delegation method. all of this works if "ChildViewController" is not embed in navigation controller.
if it is embed then i get error when unwrapping delegate (delegate!.buttonClickedByUser(word: "hello")) and error is " Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

my code looks like this:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ChildToParentProtocol
{
    func buttonClickedByUser(word: String) {
        print(word)
    } 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? ChildViewController,
            segue.identifier == "parentToChild" {
            vc.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
import UIKit

protocol ChildToParentProtocol:class {
    func buttonClickedByUser(word: String)
}


class ChildViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate:ChildToParentProtocol!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    @IBAction func childButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate!.buttonClickedByUser(word: "hello")
    }

}
```

I expect to print "hello" even if ChildViewController is embed in Navigation Controller

Comment: `if let vc = segue.destination as? ChildViewController,` returns false, right? Then, do `if let navVC =  segue.destination as? UINavigationController, let childVC = navVC. viewControllers.first as? ChildViewController {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its embedded in a NavigationController this line of code will fail:

```
if let vc = segue.destination as? ChildViewController
```

The destination won't be a `ChildViewController` it will be a `UINavigationController` with its root view controller being a `ChildViewController`.

If its inside a a navigation controller something like this should work:

```
if let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, 
    let vc = nav.viewControllers.first as? ChildViewController {
    vc.delegate = self
}
```